# Objective-C: How to Call a Instance Method

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I need to call a method I have defined as:

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender{ 
...

}
```

I want to call it in `-[UIViewController viewDidload]`

How can I call this method programmatically?

Comment: Maybe you'll find an answer [here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572448/objective-c-call-function-on-another-class

Comment: [This page][1] has also a valid answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572448/objective-c-call-function-on-another-class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[self next:nil];
```

- `self` is the object receiving the message, assuming `-next:` is defined in the same class as `-viewDidLoad`.
- `next:` is the name of the message (method).
- Since you don't use `sender`, pass the argument `nil`, meaning "nothing".

If `-next:` is defined in the App delegate but `-viewDidLoad` in some view controller, use

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
```

to refer to the app delegate. So the statement becomes

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate next:nil];
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance (still learning), you can't just use `[self next]`  with no params?

Comment: @yar: No. Also, in ObjC `-next:` and `-next` are *different* methods (the colons are significant).

Comment: Thanks @KennyTM, that helps. Why can't all these languages just be the same :)?!