# How to call a method from another method in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Can someone answer me how to call one method into another in Objective C on Xcode

Comment: This isn't very clear. Please try a longer description. Perhaps you are talking about @selector ?

Comment: suppose in didFinishinLaunchingmethod i have to call -(IBAction)check; method ...how can i call it??

Comment: Please consider using a more descriptive title for your question. This one is very general.

Answer (score 18):

The basic syntax for calling a method on an object is this:

```
[object method]; 
[object methodWithInput:input];
```

If methods returns value:

```
output = [object methodWithOutput]; 
output = [object methodWithInputAndOutput:input];
```

[More Detail](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a good example that how to call method from other class:

[OBJECTIVE C - Objective-C call method on another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572448)

**Example:**

```
SomeClass* object = [[SomeClass alloc] init]; // Create an instance of SomeClass
[object someMethod];                          // Send the someMethod message
```

Answer (score 5):

You get a pointer to an object that implements the other method and send the appropriate message (e.g. `[otherObject doSomething]`).

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
@implementation view1
(void)someMethod
{
   ......code of method...
}

@implementation view2
(void)fistMethod
{
    view1 *abc = [[view1 alloc]init];
    [abc someMethod];
    [abc release];
}
```

I hope you got it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 functions inside class(.m file):

> -(void) func1{ }
>
> -(void) func2{ }

If you want to call func2 from func1, you cannot just call func2();

instead just include `self`

That is:

```
-(void) func1{
[self:func2];
}
```