# Calling Method from another Class

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

Can Anyone Tell me why the function is Not Calling Here

Class MasterViewController.h

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController 
- (void) populateTableView;
```

Class ModelViewController.h

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
@interface ModelViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) MasterViewController *MasterViewController;
```

Class ModelViewController.m

```
@synthesize MasterViewController;
[MasterViewController.self populateTableView]; // Function Calling
```

Comment: A property? On a class? o.O **You go back reading an Objective-C language tutorial now.**

Comment: haha, thanks for the morning fun ))

Comment: i assume this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572448/objective-c-call-function-on-another-class) shall show you the way

Comment: You actually just need to rename your property to masterViewController and call a function like: [masterViewController populateTableView];

Comment: not able to understand the first Part "rename your property to masterViewController".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MasterViewController *MasterViewController;
```

Here you declared a instance variable (property) with the name `MasterViewController`, which is the same as its class name. When you sent `populateTableView` message to MasterViewController, actually, the compile treated it as a **Class Method** (`+ (void)populateTableView;`) instead of **Instance Method** (`- (void)populateTableView;`).

So you'd better declare this iVar to `masterViewController` instead (**`m` is lower case**).

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MasterViewController *masterViewController;
```

then alloc & use it in your method:

```
...
[self.masterViewController populateTableView];
```