# How to split Objective-C code into differents files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, class, split

I'm looking for a (certainly basic) thing to do in Objective-C/Cocoa : I would like to split my code into multiple files (one for functions, one for tab view N°1 methods, one for tab view N°2 methods, etc) to make my projects well organized.

I would like to be able to call functions and/or methods from my "AppDelegate.m".

But I don't know how to formulate this question correctly to find help around the web. I come from Delphi, and in Delphi you have just to create a new .PAS file and declare it in USES section.

We are in 2013, so it's certainly an ultra-basic way to code properly via XCode :)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Ah ! So, I would to put all my functions (for string manipulations for example) in another file. Then, from my main "AppDelegate.m" I'll call these functions.

Comment: Now that it seems easy, I'm sure I'll get some downvotes... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it's the same - except with the C background of Objective-C you will have to create 4 files. Two header files (.h) and two implementations (.m).

Instead of the uses section you will use the #import statement at top of the .m files.

```
#import "myClassHeader.h"
```

As this belongs to the more basic tasks in Objective-C or any C-based language, you should start with reading some [beginners tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html), how to define classes and methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Ah ok, so I just tried that. I created a new class `MyFunctionName`(.h and .m). In `AppDelegate.m` I called `#import "MyFunctionName.h"`. In `MyFunctionName.m` I created a basic function `- (void)myExample:(NSString *)Value { NSLog(Value); }`. Now, I would to be able to call it from `AppDelegate.m`.

Comment: It seems that my question correspond to this one in reality : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572448/objective-c-call-function-on-another-class I'm trying to make some tests and come back then.

Comment: Ok cool. It was that ! I didn't find anything about `MyFunctionName *myScript = [[MyFunctionName alloc] init];` before, so I didn't know how to call the function or method from 2nd class. But creating a new class was well the solution to separate my long code into small differents classes, well organized.